# CDBCriteria problems

Tags: php, yii, phpmyadmin

Iam trying out to get the result of min() in sql using cdbcriteria. I have used the code

```
$model = new Serviceproposal;
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(); 
$criteria->select = " MIN(proposal_amount) AS min_proposal_amount,ProposalDescription"; 
$criteria->condition = "Communications= 'hai'"; 
$criteria->join='LEFT JOIN Servicerequest on Servicerequest.ServiceRequestID=Serviceproposal.ServiceRequestID';
$criteria->join="LEFT JOIN user on user.country='India' AND t.user_id = user.user_id";
$results = $model->findAll($criteria);
```

But Iam getting the error `Property "Serviceproposal.min_proposal_amount" is not defined.`

```
Database:
User[user_id,name,password],
Provider[user_id,providercompany,providerdetails],
Buyer[user_id,contactinfo],
ServiceRequest[ServiceRequestID,Buyer.user_id,details,date],
ServiceProposal[ServiceProposalId,ServiceRequestID,Provider.user_id,services,propsal_rate]
```

How can I get the result of min proposal amount ?

Answer (score 1):

In model "Serviceproposal" class add proprty public $min_proposal_amount; like and then access this proprty with model object

```
class Serviceproposal extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $min_proposal_amount;

}
```

Comment: but it is showing only a dump value always. Not getting the correct answer

Comment: check value by excecuting this into phpmyadmin this problem must be in query. This should work.